# Case insensitive dictionary search with enchant

Tags: python

Is there a way to do a case-insensitive search in enchant?

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
import enchant
d = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US","mywords.txt")

d.check("Alexandria")
True
d.check("alexandria")
False
```

Both cases should return True

Comment: I think you meant to ask this on [SO], it doesn't seem to have much to do with system administration.

Comment: Arg.. you are correct. Not sure how I messed that up

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Any solution till yet?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found anywhere any information on setting Enchant for case-insensitive matching, so for the time being this is my solution, though it obviously decreases performance considerably:

```
if d.check(word) or d.check(word.capitalize()):
```

Answer (score 1):

As per you example, it should return `True`.

```
import enchant
d = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US","/home/user/yourscript.py")

a=d.check("import")
print(a)
a=d.check("Import")
print(a)
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

You can try following link, you may get some other alternatives to achieve this http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html

Comment: It is more so with proper nouns that I am speaking of

Comment: let migrate your question to respective community. I will update it.

Comment: Please Note: Enchant is not maintained anymore!